# Assign string to the pressed key

Tags: events, keyboard-events, monogame

```
            KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                _label.Text = "A";
            }
            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.B))
            {
                _label.Text = "B";
            }
            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.C))
            {
                _label.Text = "C";
            }
```

What would be a better approach to assign the _label.Text to the key that was pressed? What i want to avoid is a if/swich-statement for every character on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetPressedKeys()` method returns an array of the `Keys` enum which contains the currently pressed keys.

```
 KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();
 var keys = state.GetPressedKeys();
```

Iterate and use `ToString()` to convert the enum to string

```
 //let's assume that key a is pressed
 label.Text = keys[0].ToString(); //"a"
```

`ToString()` however doesn't solve everything. For uppercase characters you should still check if the shift key is pressed. Some special characters should be mapped as well.

A working character-key mapping can be found [here](https://github.com/gmich/Gem/blob/master/Gem.Gui/Input/KeyboardUtils.cs#L104)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MonoGame installed right now, but for WinForms, this covers all letters, numbers and keys like Shift. It is able to pickup question marks, but nothing like exclamations.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeysConverter keysConverter = new KeysConverter();
    label1.Text = keysConverter.ConvertToString(e.KeyValue);
}
```

For MonoGame, KeyboardState has an item property that should allow you to get the key that was pressed and assign it in a similar way to what I did above.